# Google Earth Engine plotting Image from ImageCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis

This is a simple operation I've done with other data sets on GEE but for some reason I can't get it to work with MODIS AOD.

Working off the [example](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_006_MCD19A2_GRANULES) on Google's developer website...

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES')
              .select('Optical_Depth_047')
              .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-01-15');
var band_viz = {
  min: 0,
  max: 500,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};

Map.addLayer(collection.mean(), band_viz, 'Optical Depth 047');
Map.setCenter(76, 13, 6);
```

We get a raster of mean AOD values

[image]

Next I want to plot the first raster from the collection.

```
var image = collection.first()
print(image)
Map.addLayer(image, band_viz, 'Optical Depth 047');
```

[image]

The image appears in the console and in the map legend, but is not visible on the map.

Here's the [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/fbd47488ab781229f134c19f451ec990) to the script. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That first image just happens to have all pixels in the `Optical_Depth_047` band masked. I modified your script, including all bands, added the geometry of the image to the map, and centered the map to the image. Go to the `Inspector` tab on the right-hand-side panel in the Code Editor and click within the image geometry. This gives you an idea of how the image looks at the location you clicked.

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES')
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-01-15')

var image = collection.first()
Map.addLayer(image.geometry(), null, 'geometry')
Map.addLayer(image, null, 'image')
Map.centerObject(image)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/05e3717a2172b646587c0480d15b88fd